# ¿Cómo puedo arreglar mi problema con el servomotor y el botón con STM32F103C8?

Tags: c, stm32

Debería hacer el funcionamiento de una pluma de estacionamiento programado en C para la placa STM32F103C8, yo utilizo:

- 1 servomotor SG90 (conectado al pin A1, TIM2_CH2, se llama TIM2_CH2)
- 1 sensor infrarrojo MH-Sensor-Series Flying-Fish (conectado al pin A10, se llama SENSOR)
- 1 push buttom (conectado al pin B0, se llama BOTON)

El funcionamiento es que cuando se presiona el botón, se activa el sensor infrarrojo y al detectar un objeto (en este caso un carrito), activa el servomotor y se levanta la pluma, dejando entrar el carrito al estacionamiento.

Yo llevo esto:

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_2); //Llamada al servo
    TIM2->CCR2 = 65; //Inicializa el serco en -90°
    int i = 0; //Variable que usaremos para guardar acción del botón
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
        
        i = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, BOTON_Pin); //Variable que guarda el botón
        
        if(i == 1) //Si se presiona el botón
        {
            if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(SENSOR_GPIO_Port, SENSOR_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_SET) //Se activa el sensor, si detecta algo
            {
            
                HAL_Delay(50);
                TIM2->CCR2 += 1;
                if(TIM2->CCR2 > 300) //Si el registro es mayor a 300 (180°)
                {
                    TIM2->CCR2 = 65; //Regresa a -90°
                }
            }
        }

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

El resultado no es como esperaba, cuando presiono el botón solo funciona el servo, y se mandan varios pulsos y el servomotor solo funciona si mantengo presionado el botón, si suelto el botón el servomotor deja de funcionar, me gustaría que se mandara un solo pulso y que funcione con el infrarrojo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funciona así, porque así lo has programado.

Lo primero que debes observar es que el programa se está corriendo en un ciclo infinito dónde, para cada iteración del ciclo lees el estado del botón y actúas solamente si el botón está presionado.

Así, a la acción de ir abriendo *poco a poco* la pluma, hasta que se abre completamente, va ocurriendo en diferentes iteraciones del ciclo, a las cuales entra solamente si se cumple la condición:

```
if(i == 1)
```

El comentario allí debiera ser, entonces, *si el botón está o sigue presionado*.

Y no solo eso, sino también debe cumplirse *al mismo tiempo* la condición de que el sensor esté activado:

```
if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(SENSOR_GPIO_Port, SENSOR_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_SET)
```

Digo *al mismo tiempo* porque la comprobación entre uno y otro se realiza con algunos nanosegundos de diferencia. En la práctica es como si fuese *al mismo tiempo*.

Si quieres que el programa actúe diferente, tocará pensar en una solución diferente.

Lo primero que se me ocurre, es que no regreses al ciclo principal hasta que se cumpla con la apertura y cierre completos de la pluma. Por ejemplo:

```
while (1) {
  if (   (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, BOTON_Pin) == 1) 
      && (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(SENSOR_GPIO_Port, SENSOR_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_SET)
     ) {
    while (1) {
      HAL_Delay(50);
      TIM2->CCR2 += 1;
      if(TIM2->CCR2 > 300) //Si el registro es mayor a 300 (180°) {
        TIM2->CCR2 = 65; //Regresa a -90°
        break;  //rompemos el ciclo interno
      }
    }
  }
}
```

En este caso, entrará al ciclo de levantar la pluma si el sensor se activa *mientras está presionado el botón*.  Es decir, igual que en la versión de la pregunta, pero ahora evalúo ambas condiciones en el mismo `if` por simplicidad en el código.

Si quieres que el programa soporte presionar el botón, soltarlo y aún así levante la pluma al activarse el sensor, deberás recordar que el botón fue presionado entre distintas iteraciones del ciclo, por ejemplo en una variable booleana que *enciendes* en la iteración que detectas que se ha presionado y mantienes encendida hasta que has terminado con las acciones a realizar (por ejemplo, al terminar de cerrar la pluma).

Sucede algo similar con el estado del sensor.

Por ejemplo:

```
botonSePresiono = 0;
while (1) {
  if ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, BOTON_Pin) == 1) {
    botonSePresiono = 1;
  }
  if (   (botonSePresiono == 1)
      && (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(SENSOR_GPIO_Port, SENSOR_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_SET)
     ) {
    while (1) {
      HAL_Delay(50);
      TIM2->CCR2 += 1;
      if(TIM2->CCR2 > 300) //Si el registro es mayor a 300 (180°) {
        TIM2->CCR2 = 65; //Regresa a -90°
        botonSePresiono = 0;
        break;  //rompemos el ciclo interno
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ahora, entonces, soportamos que el botón se presione (y se suelte) y hasta después se active el sensor para comenzar a abrir la pluma.